# html to pdf very large files php

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

hi 
i am trying to create a pdf files in php useing dompdf-0.5.1 i am creating these files from html i have a large number of data everytime i try to create a big file its getting stuck giving me errors is therey any library that i can use for large pdf files from html 
also its working for small and normal files
thanks

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Internal_Exception' with message 'Frame not found in cellmap' in E:\AppServ\www\test\include\cellmap.cls.php:237 Stack trace: #0 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\table_cell_frame_reflower.cls.php(66): Cellmap->get_frame_position(Object(Table_Cell_Frame_Decorator)) #1 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(387): Table_Cell_Frame_Reflower->reflow() #2 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\table_row_frame_reflower.cls.php(70): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #3 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(387): Table_Row_Frame_Reflower->reflow() #4 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\table_frame_reflower.cls.php(468): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #5 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(387): Table_Frame_Reflower->reflow() #6 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\block_frame_reflower.cls.php(408): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #7 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(387): Block_Frame_Reflower->reflow() #8 E:\AppServ\www\test\include\table_cell_frame_reflower.cls.php(115): Frame_Deco in E:\AppServ\www\test\include\cellmap.cls.php on line 237

Comment: It would help to have some sample HTML that causes the problem. You might consider upgrading to the 0.6.0 release of DOMPDF (currently in beta). It addresses a number of problems including this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recomend using [Webkit to PDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or [PhantomJS](https://coderwall.com/p/5vmo1g)

Comment: +1 to this choice. About a year ago I tried all available free PDF converters, and wkhtmltopdf worked better than any other. Normally you will evade many problems and crazy bugs by using it.

Answer (score 2):

Just had some headbanging going on with `DOMpdf` and found a couple of fixes along the way regarding this, so thought I'd share.

My `dompdf Frame not found in cellmap` error could be helped by editing `includes/cellmap.cls.php` and commenting out every occurence of:

```
throw new DOMPDF_Exception("Frame not found in cellmap");
```

Lines 212, 231, 257, 274

Substituting with:

```
return false;
```

This enabled me to see where my mutli-page PDF doc was actually erroring. I narrowed it down to a large image spanning more than one page (user `cms` input of course!) So I swapped the singular image for the same, chopped into 2 pieces and all is fixed.

I have also read that this error can be linked to div's spanning more that one page but found in `0.6.0` beta 3 not to be the case, as any 'fix' surrounding that made no difference, even though I have multiple div's spanning pages. The fixes suggesting replacing all div's with either 'p' or 'span' tags.

So now `DOMpdf` is rendering out `CMS` generated pages with no problems and hope this helps someone along the way,

Comment: Thanks for this. I break my head for long time with this error. In my case it was a PHP error caused by changing objects to arrays in one object. The PHP error display didn't fit the page hence the error. By commenting out those lines I figure out the error which is almost undetectable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem for days, in a huge table with rowspan and colspan, but no border-collapse:collapse (there is a known issue related to that property).

I have resolved it by adding this to the style of my table element:

```
    table
    {
       border-collapse:unset;   
    }
```

Hope it helps!